# How can I omit system databases and allow SQL Server 2008 agent job to move past ERROR_NUMBER 208?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sp-msforeachdb

I have created a SQL Server 2008 Agent job that runs against all databases on the server. I am using the undocumented MS procedure, `sp_MSforEachDB`. I am specifying only certain databases to be processed and when these databases are found, if `ERROR_NUMBER = 208`, I want a table to be created and processing to continue to the next database. I also want to omit the system databases so the tabel doesn't get created in a system database. I though by specifying the names of the databases I want to process, I could create a table where none existed. The code I show below works if the 'focus' is set on a particular database. Also, when I run it, I get a table created in the master database, which I do not want to do. What I am trying to do with the code I created is:
1. select all the databases on the SQL server with name like "xyz_%" 
2. if table "SESSIONS" exists, then delete all records older than 5 minutes
3. if table "SESSIONS" doesn't exist, then create it and continue processing -
    this is where I get the `208 error - invalid object because this table does not exist`
When the job sees there is no Sessions table, the job stops and no other databases are processed. I need all the named databases in 1 to be processed. If the SESSIONS table is not present, I get a 208 error that says "Invalid object name 'master.SchemaName.sessions'. If I set the 'focus' to the database without the sessions table, my code runs and the tables is created but I still get an error 208 - Invalid object name 'master.SchemaName.sessions'. No other error are displayed.

If someone could look at my code to see where my problem is, that would be great.

I have verified that I am getting the 208 error by using the Try Catch below. I also get error 2760 on the 2nd Try Catch that says the specified schema doesn't exist or I don't have access. I am an admin on this server.

I have been using SQL for a few years and I don't consider myself an expert. I have researched this on Google to come up with the code I have below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
declare @ERROR INT

BEGIN TRY

exec sp_MSforeachdb 'IF "[?]" NOT IN ("master", "model","msdb", "tempdb")
BEGIN
 DELETE FROM [?].schema.sessions WHERE name like ''xyz_%''
 AND sessionStart <DATEADD(mi, -5,GETDATE())
END'                  

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
SELECT  ERROR_NUMBER() AS error_number,  ERROR_MESSAGE() AS error_message
    SELECT @ERROR = ERROR_NUMBER()
    If @ERROR = 208
    BEGIN TRY
     /* create the Sessions table */
     BEGIN
     CREATE TABLE  [SCHEMA].[SESSIONS](
       [authuser] [varchar](30) NULL,
       [sessionID] [char](36) NULL,
       [sessionStart] [datetime] NULL)

grant select,delete on reviewadmin.sessions to public;
     END
    END TRY  
 BEGIN CATCH 
  SELECT  ERROR_NUMBER() AS error_number,  ERROR_MESSAGE() AS error_message
 END CATCH 
 END CATCH
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `DB_ID()`, I believe the `DB_ID()` is always 1-4 (unless you have a [distribution database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms183524.aspx)). In theory, just check to see if DB_ID() is greater than 4:

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb 'IF DB_ID(''?'')) > 4
BEGIN
 DELETE FROM [?].schema.sessions WHERE name like ''xyz_%''
 AND sessionStart <DATEADD(mi, -5,GETDATE())
END'
```

Also it doesn't look like you're using the correct database in the error handler - surely your try catch that creates the table should be in the call to `sp_MSforeachdb` as well?

I mean in your text you're running for each db, including this in a try catch:

```
CREATE TABLE [?].[SCHEMA].[SESSIONS]
(
   [authuser]     [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
   [sessionID]    [CHAR](36) NULL,
   [sessionStart] [DATETIME] NULL
)
```

One more thing - at the moment you seem to have hard coded the value `reviewadmin.sessions` in your permission granting code - I assume you meant that to be your new `[?].[Schema].[Sessions]` table - again which should be in the call to `sp_MSforeachdb` so it knows which database to run on.

I hope I've given you enough to go on, I'm not at a machine where I can write & test the whole thing I'm afraid!

---

If you just want databases with the name `xyz_%` :

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb 'IF DB_NAME() LIKE ''xyz_%''
BEGIN
 DELETE FROM [?].schema.sessions WHERE name like ''xyz_%''
 AND sessionStart <DATEADD(mi, -5,GETDATE())
END'
```

Note we can now skip the check for DB_ID > 4, since none of the system databases match your naming convention anyway.

---

OK, I've rethought this. Rather than trying and then catching the error if it fails, how about this new plan:

1. Check if the database matches the naming convention you want.
2. Check if the table exists.
3. Create the table if it doesn't, grant permissions as before.
4. Do the insert.

This should hopefully do it:

```
EXEC Sp_msforeachdb 'IF ''?'' LIKE ''xyz_%''
                    BEGIN
                        IF OBJECT_ID(''?.REVIEWADMIN.Sessions'', ''U'') IS NULL
                        BEGIN
                            CREATE TABLE [?].ReviewAdmin.Sessions
                            (
                                [authuser]     [VARCHAR](30) NULL,
                                [sessionID]    [CHAR](36) NULL,
                                [sessionStart] [DATETIME] NULL
                            )

                            grant select,delete on reviewadmin.sessions to public;

                        END

                        DELETE FROM [?].ReviewAdmin.Sessions
                        WHERE sessionStart < DATEADD(mi, -5,GETDATE())

                    END'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the code 'IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4 and that does appear to have removed the system databases from being processed. Is there a way I can only have this code work for all databases with the name like xyz_% ? I only need to process databases with the names like xyz_%. The code you suggested worked fine for the system databases - there are other databases that exist that I do not want to include and specifying them by name like xyz_% is what I would like to do. I would like to fix this first and then address the other issues.

Comment: For schema - I will be using reviewadmin.sessions so reviewadmin can be substituted for [schema} above.

Comment: I added your code and now I get an error 207 - invalid column 'name'. I tried DB_NAME and I got the same error except with DB_NAME as the invalid column.

Comment: @user1927354 Odd, works for me. Try putting `''?''` into the first line like so: `IF DB_NAME(''?'') LIKE ''xyz_%''`

Comment: If I use 'IF DB_NAME like "xyz_%" ', do I even need the where name like "xyz_%"?

Comment: @user1927354 I presumed that `WHERE name like ''xyz_%''` on line 3 was something to do with your sessions table, not the database it's running on. It's nothing I added - if you don't need it, get rid of that bit from the where clause.

Comment: I just tried your change and now I get error 245 - Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'master' to data type int.

Comment: @user1927354 OK ignore that last comment - try this: `IF ''?'' LIKE ''xyz_%''`

Comment: That worked. Executed successfully. I tested and if the sessions table doesn't exist, I get error 208 invalid object name 'xyz_revieweadmin.sessions - which makes sense because there is no table. When this happens, I want to create the table. I also see error 2760 - the specified schema name "REVIEWADMIN" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

Comment: @user1927354 Yeah as I said in the original answer, you'll want a try catch _inside_ the `BEGIN ... END`, and put your error check/table creation code inside there. With regards to the error message, `xyz_revieweadmin.sessions` isn't a complete name, it should be of the form `Database.Schema.Table` - what you've given me is `database.table`. That can't have come from the  `DELETE FROM [?].schema.sessions` surely, it's missing the schema bit.

Comment: I moved the try catch as you instructed. I get error 2760 again with the same text as above. It must be as you mention about the name. I say 'Create Table.REVIEWADMIN.SESSIONS and the table needs to be created in xyz_dbname.REVIEWADMIN.

Comment: @user1927354 Does the `REVIEWADMIN` schema exist on each database? If not, you'll need to create that first.

Comment: Yes. REVIEWADMIN does exist on each database that is named xyz_dbname.

Comment: Your last code worked great! I have run a few tests and it is doing what it is supposed to do. Thank you very much for your help today! It is appreciated.

Comment: @user1927354 No problem, I actually tested it this time! Please consider accepting my answer - see the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) if you're not sure how :-)