# SQL Server : drop all databases except the system ones

Tags: sql-server, powershell

In PowerShell I am using the following code to delete all non system SQL Server databases:

```
invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqlInstanceName -U $sqlUser -P $sqlPass -Query "
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
  'IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4
  BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [?] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
    DROP DATABASE [?]
  END'
"
```

And it seems to do the job. But when I re-run it I get:

> invoke-sqlcmd : Option 'SINGLE_USER' cannot be set in database 'master'.
>   Option 'SINGLE_USER' cannot be set in database 'tempdb'.
>   At C:\tmp\drop.ps1:19 char:5
>       +     invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqlInstanceName -U $sqlUser -P $sq ...
>       +     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>           + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlPowerShellSqlExecutionException
>           + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

I thought `IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4` would skip any system dbs:

[How can I omit system databases and allow SQL Server 2008 agent job to move past ERROR_NUMBER 208?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14320886/how-can-i-omit-system-databases-and-allow-sql-server-2008-agent-job-to-move-past)

How do I make it terminate gracefully if only system dbs (master, model, msdb, tempdb) are found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect what is happening here is syntax checking before the actual evaluation of `IF`. You need to introduce another level of "dynamism" to your query.

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
  'IF DB_ID(''?'') > 4
  BEGIN
    EXEC (''ALTER DATABASE [?] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE [?]'' )
  END'
```